# Как записать дату/время в начало строк лога?

Tags: shell, bash, linux

Некий скрипт на bash выполняет бэкап и попутно пишет лог. Нужно, чтобы каждая строка лога начиналась с даты и времени. У меня пока что получилось вот так:

```
LOG='./logfile'  
echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %T") Начало копирования файлов >> $LOG  
...  
echo $(date +"%y-%m-%d %T") Окончание копирования файлов >> $LOG
```

Существует ли способ писать это короче?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну так сделайте функцию log и используйте её. Что-то вроде этого

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/path/to/my/log/file

log(){
   message="$(date +"%y-%m-%d %T") $@"
   echo $message
   echo $message >>$LOGFILE
}

log "Начало копирования файлов"
# ....
log "Окончание копирования файлов"
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!